# ¿Cómo puedo pasar de una variable character a una variable numérica?

Tags: rstudio

Tengo una pregunta donde las respuestas son de tipo character `("Nunca (1)","Muy raramente (2)","Pocas veces (3)","Mitad de las veces (4)","Muchas veces (5)","Casi siempre (6)","Siempre (7)","No tuvo lugar (x)")))`

Necesito pasarla a numérica pero tengo problema como la  variable "no tuvo lugar (x)" ya que el puntaje sería 0 pero no es un missing. En este caso los puntajes son importantes para luego sacar un score.

Lo he intentado así pero no funciona:

```
l$preg1 <-factor(l$preg1)
class(l$preg1)
as.numeric(factor(l$preg1, levels = c("Nunca (1)","Muy raramente (2)","Pocas veces (3)","Mitad de las veces (4)","Muchas veces (5)","Casi siempre (6)","Siempre (7)","No tuvo lugar (x)")))
class(l$preg1)
l$preg1 <- as.integer(l$preg1)
class(l$preg1)
l$preg1 <-as.numeric(as.character(l$preg1))
class(l$preg1)
```

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Bienvenida Candelaria a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: No llego a entender que es lo que buscas, podrías agregar una muestra de los datos de `l$preg1`, por ejemplo `str(l$preg1)`

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. El problema es que tengo una variable de tipo character de una pregunta que tiene 8 posibles opciones a elegir cada una con un puntaje arbitrario asignado para luego poder hacer calculos.

Comment: > l$preg1 <- factor(l$preg1)
> levels(l$preg1)
[1] "Casi siempre (6)"       "Mitad de las veces (4)"
[3] "Muchas veces (5)"       "Muy raramente (2)"     
[5] "Nunca (1)"              "Pocas veces (3)"       
[7] "Siempre (7)"

Comment: Aquí converti la variable a factor para que se pueda ver que en la pregunta 1 existe estas repsuestas. Aquí nadie eligio la opción "no tuvo lugar" entonces pude ordenar el factor y obtener los puntos que corresponden pero en otras preguntas los participantes no eligieron alguna de estas opciones y si eligieron la opción "no tuvo lugar" y ahi viene mi problema.